# Core data and one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I have two entities:

```
Profiles<-->>Events
```

Now, I want the user to be able to add a profile and then be able to add events to that profile.

I'm having a hard time getting my mind out of the relational database world and into core data, but as I understand it, whenever I add an Event, I'll have to set the relationship for the profile..which makes sense to me.  But when I add the Profile initially, do I have to tell the Event entity anything, or does core data resolve that when I add an Event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to [read the Core Data guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) from start to finish. It answers all these questions, and will save you a ton of headache. I'm a big fan of Core Data, but it is a massive framework that cannot be learned by puttering around and just trying things on your own (that is what I tried first as well, and got very frustrated and wasted more time undoing what I thought I had learned). Most importantly, don't think of CD as an ORM or database mapper - it's really an object graph manager that also handles persisting that object graph for you (as well as undo management, object 'schema' evolution, and more)

The short answer to your question is that no, you don't have to tell CD everything about your objects right away. You can create a Profile, set a few attributes on it, save it, come back days later and then start adding Events that are related.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Ryan core data is different from relational DB , in your example you can add the event separately and after that you can add the relation to the profile in different command .

```
[_profile1 addEventObject:_event1]
[_profile1 addEventObject:_event2]
[_profile1 addEventObject:_event3]
```